# XML to XML using XSLT remove duplicates

Tags: xslt

Below is an input xml file:

```
<assets>
    <item>
        <file_name>file123</file_name>
        <description>testing</description>
        <created>date</created>
        <metadata>
            <guest>name</guest>
            <webinfo>test</webinfo>
            <albumorder>3</albumorder>
            <albumorder>3</albumorder>
        </metadata>
    </item>
</assets>
```

From the above xml metadata/albumorder is having duplicate. I want to keep only one albumorder element. How to remove the duplicate elements.

Result file should be like:

```
<assets>
    <item>
        <file_name>file123</file_name>
        <description>testing</description>
        <created>date</created>
        <metadata>
            <guest>name</guest>
            <webinfo>test</webinfo>
            <albumorder>3</albumorder>
        </metadata>
    </item>
</assets>
```

Comment: I am new to xslt..finding it difficult to resolve it..i search a lot of scenario but could not come across any scenario exactly matching to my scenario..Can anyone help me with the code for this?

Comment: maybe you haven't noticed, but it's not good style to ask questions without upvoting/accepting the answers - also check your other questions ...

Answer (score 0):

The following copies only elements, which don't have a same named preceeding sibling element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[name(.) = name(current())])">
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is pattern called "XSL identity template" or "XSL identity transformation", that will keep all XML except for rules you define to change certain elements.

kiwiwings already pointed out the solution, I would just integrate it in the identity template, otherwise you would loose XML comments, attributes, and processing instructions (none of them are present in your XML, but someone else may have them).

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="comment()|processing-instruction()|text()">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[name(.) = name(current())])">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="comment()|processing-instruction()|text()|*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```